# WPF Added button click not firing

Tags: wpf, events

I have a grid of custom buttons with 1 column. When i click on one it creates a new row, with its own custom buttons (depending on which was clicked). When i click on those new button it's supposed to continue but the click event doesn't even fire. It only works on the 1rst column

First set of button :

```
 public ModificationPage(List<Tools.Modele> lm)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        int index = 0;
        lm.ForEach(model =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine(model.Libelle);
            ModifButton b = new ModifButton(model,0,index);
            Grid.SetColumn(b,0);
            Grid.SetRow(b,index);
            b.Click += ButtonClicked;
            grid.Children.Add(b);
            index++;
        });
    }


    private void ButtonClicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Handled = true; //Without this the event is fired multiples times and add more than 1 row. Removing it doesn't fix the problem
        ModifButton b = sender as ModifButton;
        Console.WriteLine(b.model);
        AddFollowing(b)
    }



  private async void AddFollowing(ModifButton b)
    {
        List<List<String>> rep = await SQL.Procedure(Constant.RecupModel, sp);
        grid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition());
        int index = 0;
        rep.ForEach(item =>
        {
            Modele m = new Modele(int.Parse(item[0]), item[1], item[4]);
            ModifButton mb = new ModifButton(m, grid.ColumnDefinitions.Count - 1,index);
            b.Click += ButtonClicked; //This one doesn't work
            Grid.SetColumn(mb, grid.ColumnDefinitions.Count - 1);
            Grid.SetRow(mb, index);
            grid.Children.Add(mb);
            index++;
        });
```

Comment: b.Click += ButtonClicked;  should be mb.Click += ButtonClicked;  You are adding  grid.Children.Add(mb); in function AddFollowing

Comment: So simple, i feel stupid. Thank you !